# nextAuth: 'Users authenticated with the Credentials provider are not persisted in the database.'

Tags: next-auth

If I understand this correctly it means that if I want to do 'my own' auth, the database entry for the user will be deleted after he logs out. How can I possibly work with this then? After all, how do I deal with data that is tied to the user?

Answer (score 0):

as per note in [this](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials)

using jwt strategy, will not persist session in database.
session: {
strategy: 'jwt'
}

[this](https://discord.com/channels/966627436387266600/1037312883572342794/1043057266770845716) discussion may helps you out:
however, it is not about persisting session into the database.